# Where do assets for Minecraft mods go?

Tags: java, assets, minecraft-modding

I found this link:
[Where do I store (or how do I refer to) textures for custom blocks?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/71906/where-do-i-store-or-how-do-i-refer-to-textures-for-custom-blocks)

Unfortunately, the answer did not explain where that assets folder actually is. As such, I can't figure out where the textures themselves go.

I'm trying to replicate the tutorial on minecraftforge.net, so the mod's ID is "generic". For some reason, though, the assets folders all contain folders called "genericmod".

Basically: Can someone give me the exact path I should go to, starting from forge_1710_src, to put my graphics in?

Answer (score 1):

```
forge_1710_src/src/java <--this is where your code lives, possibly inside more directories

forge_1710_src/src/resources/assets/[MODID]/textures/blocks <--where block textures go
```

http://www.minecraftforge.net/wiki/Icons_and_Textures

Answer (score 0):

Why not store fhem inside the jar file? Then you could reference them as YourMainClass.class.getResourcesAsStream(new File(path fo your file))

Comment: He wants the source file path for where the files are natively loaded from, which when compiled, *is* inside the jar.

Comment: Oh. Cheers. Inside two packages inside src folder, assets.themodsname.textures.blocks and assets.themodsname.textures.item